# Eclipse Navigator contextMenu

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing an eclipse product. I added a navigator view to the plugin and now I would like to customize its context menu by removing some of the default actions and by adding some custom actions.

How can I remove actions from the menu? And how can I add my actions?

Is there a way to create a context menu at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end i solved in this way:

- I created a navigator viewer, which
  extend o.e.ui.navigator.viewer, and i
  provide a popupMenu specifying
  "allowPlatformContributions = false". 
  Then i created as many insertionPoint
  as i need for my context menu. The
  actions i want eclipse to provide in
  the context menu are contained in
  group.new, group.edit,
  group.reorganize. The resulting xml is:

  ```
  <extension
       point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer">
   .....
    <viewer viewerId="...">
       <popupMenu
             allowsPlatformContributions="false">
          <insertionPoint
                name="group.xvr.management"
                separator="true">
          </insertionPoint>
          <insertionPoint
                name="group.new"
                separator="true">
          </insertionPoint>
          <insertionPoint
                name="group.edit"
                separator="true">
          </insertionPoint>
          <insertionPoint
                name="group.reorganize">
          </insertionPoint>
          <insertionPoint
                name="group.xvr.launch"
                separator="true">
          </insertionPoint>
       </popupMenu>
       </viewer>
       ...
       </extension>
  ```

  the other two group names,
  group.xvr.launch and
  group.xvr.management, are custom
  placeholder for my actions.
- then i extended
  o.e.ui.navigator.navigatorContent
  creating my custom content which i
  bind to the viewer. I added to the
  navigator content as many
  actionProvider as i need. In each one
  of them i override the method
  fillContextMenu to provide custom
  action to the context menu.

  ```
  @Override
  public void fillContextMenu(IMenuManager menu) {
      menu.appendToGroup("group.xvr.launch", new CommandContributionItem(new CommandContributionItemParameter(...)));
  menu.appendToGroup("group.xvr.launch", new CommandContributionItem(new CommandContributionItemParameter(...)));
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend o.e.ui.navigator.navigatorContent and provide an actionProvider.

Comment: yes..it is true..but i have to do more to completely control the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

hyou have to extend the navigator view, and override the context menu (should be the createPartControl Method). right now i don't have access to the eclipse source.

hope this helps.